# Oracle - Count a select based on a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, subquery

I need to count the result from a sub query based on the main query

I would like to count how many Vehicle there are with the year 2021.

How would I generate the result of this query with a column counting each green car that has the year 2021. Example below

Table 1

| ID | Vehicle |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Car |
| 2 | motorcycle |
| 3 | bicycle |

Table 2

| ID | ID_TABLE1 | COLOR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | RED |
| 2 | 1 | GREEN |
| 3 | 3 | BLACK |
| 4 | 1 | GREEN |

Table 3

| ID | ID_TABLE1 | YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2021 |
| 2 | 1 | 2020 |
| 3 | 3 | 2021 |
| 3 | 1 | 2020 |

My try, its not working

```
select t1.Vehicle, t2.color from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id_table1 
left joint(select count* table 3 t3 where t3.year = 2020 ) tbyear on t1.id = t3.id_table1
```

The final table would look like this:

| NAME | NAME | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CAR | green | 2 |
| motorcycle | red | 0 |
| bicycle | black | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

It should works like this if you want to see Year, Vehicle, color

```
select t3.Year, t1.Vehicle, t2.color, COUNT(*)
from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id_table1 
inner join table3 t3 on t1.id = t3.id_table1 
GROUP BY t3.Year, t1.Vehicle, t2.color
```

If you don't need some filed - delete it in select and group by.

But it's not the best solution - when you haven't sales in 2021 for Green Car (for example)- you will not see it in a result query that's why i should ask: Do you need to see it? (for example 0 instead of skipping this row)

Am i correct about the task?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want `outer apply()`:

```
select 
 t1.Vehicle, t2.color, tbyear.*
from table1 t1 
     inner join table2 t2 
           on t1.id = t2.id_table1 
     outer apply(
        select count(*) cnt 
        from table3 t3 
        where t1.id = t3.id_table1 
        and t3.year = 2020
     ) tbyear;
```

Full example with test data:

```sql
with -- test data:
 Table1(ID,Vehicle) as (
select 1, 'Car'        from dual union all
select 2, 'motorcycle' from dual union all
select 3, 'bicycle'    from dual 
)
,Table2(ID, ID_TABLE1, COLOR) as (
select 1, 2, 'RED'   from dual union all
select 2, 1, 'GREEN' from dual union all
select 3, 3, 'BLACK' from dual union all
select 4, 1, 'GREEN' from dual
)
,Table3(ID,ID_TABLE1,YEAR) as (
select 1, 2, 2021 from dual union all
select 2, 1, 2020 from dual union all
select 3, 3, 2021 from dual union all
select 3, 1, 2020 from dual
)
-- end test data
select 
 t1.Vehicle, t2.color, tbyear.*
from table1 t1 
     inner join table2 t2 
           on t1.id = t2.id_table1 
     outer apply(
        select count(*) cnt 
        from table3 t3 
        where t1.id = t3.id_table1 
        and t3.year = 2020
     ) tbyear
```

Results:

```
EHICLE    COLOR        CNT
---------- ----- ----------
motorcycle RED            0
Car        GREEN          2
bicycle    BLACK          0
Car        GREEN          2
```